# DevExpress Success modal after some validations and set Timeout

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, devexpress

I have here a gridview that allows the user to select a row for cancelation.
After selecting a row and supplying other fields I want to create a validations that
will check if all the fields are supplied correctly while checking I want to show a "loading effect" and after that once the process succeed
I want to create a modal after the button clicked that says "Record Save" and will disappear after a few seconds and the page will redirect to its corresponding page (Example: View page). Also I use splitter So that my main page is my index page and other page will be loaded from my index's navbar and will display at the center part of my page.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout3" runat="server" Theme="" >
    <Items>
    <dx:LayoutItem ShowCaption="False" HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="100%"> 
    <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
    <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer ID="LayoutItemNestedControlContainer2" runat="server" >
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="true" EnableTheming="True" Theme="Material" DataSourceID = "grid" KeyFieldName = "cancel_no" Width="100%" >
<SettingsBehavior ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="True" />
<SettingsCommandButton>
</SettingsCommandButton>

<Columns>
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="true" Width="60px" Caption="Cancel" VisibleIndex="0"></dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="No" ReadOnly="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1" Visible = "false">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
<EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="RefNo" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2" Visible = "false">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Item" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
<CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle">
</CellStyle>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Code" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4" Visible = "false">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Type" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
<CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle">
</CellStyle>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>


<Settings VerticalScrollBarMode="Visible" VerticalScrollableHeight="250" />
<SettingsDataSecurity AllowInsert="False" AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="False" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
</dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
</LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
</dx:LayoutItem>
</Items>
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>

<dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout5" runat="server" Theme="Mulberry">
<SettingsAdaptivity AdaptivityMode="SingleColumnWindowLimit" SwitchToSingleColumnAtWindowInnerWidth="800" />
<Items>
<dx:LayoutGroup Caption="Approvals" ColCount="3" SettingsItemCaptions-Location="Top" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%">

<Items>

<dx:LayoutItem Caption = "Checked By">
<LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
<dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox5" runat="server"  Theme="Metropolis" Border-BorderStyle="NotSet" BorderLeft-BorderStyle="None" BorderRight-BorderStyle="None" BorderTop-BorderStyle="None" />
</dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
</LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
</dx:LayoutItem>
</Items>

<SettingsItemCaptions Location="Top"></SettingsItemCaptions>
</dx:LayoutGroup>

</Items>
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>

<dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout4" runat="server" >
<SettingsAdaptivity AdaptivityMode="SingleColumnWindowLimit" SwitchToSingleColumnAtWindowInnerWidth="800" />
<Items>
<dx:LayoutGroup ShowCaption="False" ColCount="1" SettingsItemCaptions-Location="Top" HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="100%">
<Items>
<dx:LayoutItem ShowCaption="False">
<LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
<dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Submit" Theme="Material" />
</dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
</LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
<Border BorderStyle="None" />
</dx:LayoutItem>

<dx:LayoutItem ShowCaption="False">
<LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
<dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton2" runat="server" Text="Clear" Theme="Material"></dx:ASPxButton>
</dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
</LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
</dx:LayoutItem>
</Items>

<SettingsItemCaptions Location="Top"></SettingsItemCaptions>
</dx:LayoutGroup>
</Items>
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>
```

And here is my backend. I want to create a validation that will check if it has a "Checked checkbox" if not then the saving will not proceed or another modal will pop that will says "No checkbox is selected" something like that.

```
Protected Sub ASPxButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ASPxButton1.Click
        getIndeces()
        save_cancelitem()
        save_canceldetails()
End Sub                                    

Protected Sub save_cancelitem()
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prod").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "save_tocancel"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_hdrno", ASPxTextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_agen", ASPxComboBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_adver", ASPxComboBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_refno", ASPxComboBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_teldate", "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_docno", ASPxComboBox3.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_reason", "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_authby", "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_client", "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_aprv", "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_SD", "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnc_recvby", "")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
    End Sub



Protected Sub save_canceldetails()
        Dim rkey As String = Session("rkey").ToString
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ofs").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select Product, Version, Frequency, Length, Program, ordd_teledte, Billing_Cost, Internal_Cost, iscancelled from canceltbl where rkey = @rkey", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rkey", rkey)
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dta As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dta)
        Dim dt_hdrno As DataColumn = dta.Columns.Add("dt_hdrno", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Dim dt_rkey As DataColumn = dta.Columns.Add("dt_rkey", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        For Each r As DataRow In dta.Rows
            r(dt_hdrno) = ASPxTextBox2.Text
            r(dt_rkey) = rkey
        Next
        Dim bulkdtl As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ofs").ConnectionString)
        bulkdtl.DestinationTableName = "cancel_dtl"
        bulkdtl.ColumnMappings.Add("Item", "item_cancel")
        bulkdtl.ColumnMappings.Add("Code", "item_code")
        bulkdtl.ColumnMappings.Add("Type", "item_type")

    End Sub
```

Comment: I see a lot of ***I wants***, but ***not*** any here is what I tried and where I am stuck. We will help but are not here to write it for you. Please update with what you have tried on these ***wants***.

Comment: @Zaggler Sorry for that. I'm a DevExpress newbie and still finding an idea on how can I achieve that.

Comment: Devexpress support answers questions within a day or so and will show you in the right direction